# Where can I find the Gartner Magic Quadrant for Web Content Management 2015

Tags: content-management-system

I heard that the Gartner Magic Quadrant for Web Content Management 2015 was released. I would like to check which vendors in the WCM space are part of the Gartner Magic Quadrant for Web Content Management 2015. Does anybody know where I can download the report?

Comment: Someone'd have to use a search engine here, so perhaps you could do it? I'd guess the Gartner website will have a link to it, though you might have to sign up to download it.

Answer (score 7):

Hi here's a complimentary copy of the [Gartner Magic Quadrant report](http://onehippo.com/gartnermq) from Hippo CMS. Hippo is the only open source Java CMS to figure in the report.